# Proof of Kunneth formula on Vick's Homology Theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

[image]
[image]
I am reading Vick's Homology Theory. He tries to use the acyclic model theorem to give the Kunneth formula for the singular homology of a product space. But in the proof he claims that the functor $S_*(X\times Y)$ has $\mathscr M$ as a model. But I don't see why this is true. For example, how is the diagonal in a square generated by such elements? Or have I misunderstood this functor? What is the image of a morphism between space pairs under this functor? the notations are in the pictures. Thanks!

Comment: see https://amathew.wordpress.com/2010/09/12/some-applications-of-acyclic-models-in-algebraic-topology/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functor $T_*(X,Y) = S_*(X \times Y)$ has even a smaller set of models on which it is free. This is
$$\mathscr M' = \{M_p =  (\sigma^p, \sigma^p) \mid p \ge 0 \} \subset \mathscr M .$$
As the element $e_p \in T_p(M_p) = S_p(\sigma^p \times \sigma^p)$ we take the diagonal map $\sigma^p \to \sigma^p \times \sigma^p$.

Clearly each $T_p(\tau_X,\tau_Y)(e_p) = (\tau_X \times \tau_Y) \circ e_p $, where $\tau_X :  \sigma^p \to X, \tau_Y :  \sigma^p \to Y$ are arbitrary, is a singular simplex in $X \times Y$ and thus a generator of $S_p(X \times Y)$. Conversely, let $\tau : \sigma^p \to X \times Y $ be a singular $p$-simplex and $\tau_X :  \sigma^p \to X, \tau_Y :  \sigma^p \to Y$ be the two component maps. Then $\tau = T_p(\tau_X,\tau_Y)(e_p)$ which shows that all generators of $S_p(X \times Y)$ have the desired form.